# Passing a struct trough several functions in C?

Tags: c, struct

In my code I got a struct of this kind and two functions:

```
typedef struct {
    char team;
    int score;
} Player;

myfunc1 (Player *players) {
    players->score = 105;
    myfunc(?);
}

myfunc2(?) {
    //change again points and team character
}
```

And in main I create an array of that struct and pass it to a function:

```
int main () {
    Player players[2]

    myfunc1(players)

}
```

I get to work the first function, but I don't know what argument I should pass from the first to the second to modify the array of players[2] created in main.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can again use a simple pointer to access the data from `players`:

```
void myfunc2 (Player *player)
{
    players->score = 123;
}
```

Call it from your `myfunc1` like this:

```
myfunc2(players);
```

You will actually pass an address to Player structure stored in pointer `Player* players` (in function `myfunc1`) into local pointer variable `Player *player` in function `myfunc2`.

To modify players[1] in your `main` function, call `myfunc1` like this:

```
int main () {
    Player players[2]

    myfunc1(&players[1]); // & = give an address to your struct
}
```

Be careful about array indexes, they do start from zero, so if yu have an array with capacity of two (`Player players[2]`) then there are only two valid indexes: `0` an `1`. If you access indexes beyound the capacity your code will sooner or later crash.

Comment: Oh thanks, that is was what i was actually looking for. So to pass the struct array trough for example 5 functions all the fnctions receive the same arg.. cool